# Python logging config that writes to Qt widget

Tags: qt, logging, python-2.7, sys

I haven't quite found the answer yet in other threads with similar titles. Let's say I have a logging.conf that looks like this:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,analyzer

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,analyzerFileHandler

[formatters]
keys=consoleFormatter,logFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,analyzerFileHandler

[logger_analyzer]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,analyzerFileHandler
qualname=analyzer
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_analyzerFileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=logFormatter
args=('analyzer.log','w')

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s | %(message)s
datefmt=%m/%d/%Y %X

[formatter_logFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s | %(message)s
datefmt=%m/%d/%Y %X
```

A *logger = logging.getLogger('analyzer')* will send text to the log file and the console, how can I make that sys.stdout go towards a QPlainTextEdit() widget instead of the console?

**edit**

OK looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465971/redirecting-output-in-pyqt) I made this code. The post's code is good, but for some reason it doesn't address the issue, you can comment out all the instances of logger and still end up with print events going to Qwidget. The logger, as is, has no real interaction with the rest of the program, it is just there. I thought I could rectify the problem by writing a class that took whatever I wanted as text and sent it off to print and logger respectively:

```
import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig
from os import getcwd
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject,\
                         pyqtSignal

from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, \
                        QVBoxLayout, \
                        QPushButton, \
                        QTextBrowser,\
                        QApplication

class XStream(QObject):
    _stdout = None
    _stderr = None

    messageWritten = pyqtSignal(str)

    def flush( self ):
        pass

    def fileno( self ):
        return -1

    def write( self, msg ):
        if ( not self.signalsBlocked() ):
            self.messageWritten.emit(unicode(msg))

    @staticmethod
    def stdout():
        if ( not XStream._stdout ):
            XStream._stdout = XStream()
            sys.stdout = XStream._stdout
        return XStream._stdout

    @staticmethod
    def stderr():
        if ( not XStream._stderr ):
            XStream._stderr = XStream()
            sys.stderr = XStream._stderr
        return XStream._stderr

class XLogger():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    def debug(self,text):
        print text
        self.logger.debug(text)
    def info(self,text):
        print text
        self.logger.info(text)
    def warning(self,text):
        print text
        self.logger.warning(text)
    def error(self,text):
        print text
        self.logger.error(text)

class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        # setup the ui
        self._console = QTextBrowser(self)
        self._button  = QPushButton(self)
        self._button.setText('Test Me')

        # create the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self._console)
        layout.addWidget(self._button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # create connections
        XStream.stdout().messageWritten.connect( self._console.insertPlainText )
        XStream.stderr().messageWritten.connect( self._console.insertPlainText )

        self.xlogger = XLogger('analyzer')

        self._button.clicked.connect(self.test)

    def test( self ):

        # log some stuff
        self.xlogger.debug("Testing debug")
        self.xlogger.info('Testing info')
        self.xlogger.warning('Testing warning')
        self.xlogger.error('Testing error')

if ( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    fileConfig(''.join([getcwd(),'/logging.conf']))

    app = None
    if ( not QApplication.instance() ):
        app = QApplication([])

    dlg = MyDialog()
    dlg.show()
```

The "cross logger" sends everything to the log and to the Qwidget, however it also sends everything but debug to the aptana console:

```
02/05/2013 17:38:42 - analyzer - INFO | Testing info
02/05/2013 17:38:42 - analyzer - WARNING | Testing warning
02/05/2013 17:38:42 - analyzer - ERROR | Testing error
```

While the analyzer.log has:

```
02/05/2013 17:38:42 - DEBUG | Testing debug
02/05/2013 17:38:42 - INFO | Testing info
02/05/2013 17:38:42 - WARNING | Testing warning
02/05/2013 17:38:42 - ERROR | Testing error
```

Weird that debug is the only one who doesn't make it to the Aptana console, removing *consoleHandler* from handlers under [logger_analyzer] in my logging.conf solves the problem of it writing out to the Aptana console, probably has something to do with the *args=(sys.stdout,)* under [handler_consoleHandler]. I suppose it solves my problem without having to code in a handler for the Qtext object and thus negate the logging.conf file. If someone has a more elegant solution to using a logging.conf file that somehow manages to redirect its console output to a Qwidget of your choice, please feel free to post. Thanks.