# Signals and Slots PyQt

Tags: pyqt, signals-slots

I came across some new way of connecting signals and slots in PyQt. Please have a look at this link. [How to capture output of Python's interpreter and show in a Text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356336/how-to-capture-output-of-pythons-interpreter-and-show-in-a-text-widget). Here the textWritten(signal)=self.normalOutputWritten(function) are connected directly. It is working. Can someone elaborate on this new way of connections.

Rephrasing the question:
 [How to capture output of Python's interpreter and show in a Text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356336/how-to-capture-output-of-pythons-interpreter-and-show-in-a-text-widget).
In the above link, testWritten is defined as pyqtSignal and self.normalOutput is the slot function. Usually, we connect using the old or new styles but here they just used the '=' symbol. It is working. Please explain this new way.

Answer (score 2):

When you create some PyQt object, you can set properties and connect signals uising keyword arguments to `__init__()`, e.g.:

```
button = QtGui.QPushButton(clicked=on_click, text='My button', checkable=True)
```

For more info see:

[PyQt Support for Qt Properties](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qt_properties.html)

[Frequently overlooked (and practical) PyQt4 features](http://blog.odnous.net/2011/06/frequently-overlooked-and-practical.html)

Comment: I am familiar with the old and new styles of connecting slots and signals. All of them use 'connect' . Here, testWritten signal is being connected to self.normalOutput function by using '='. Please check my updated question. thanks.

Comment: @kasa, Are you talking about ``sys.stdout = EmittingStream(textWritten=self.normalOutputWritten)`` It's same as ``QPushButtton(clicked=self.on_click)`` i.e. keyword argument. Did you read links from answer?