# Pyqt: 'dynamically' append to qtextedit from function

Tags: python, dynamic, pyqt4, stdout, qtextedit

There is a button in my pyqt gui that when clicked runs a function that does some lengthy math calculations. Inside this function there were a lot of print statements like:

```
print "finished calculating task1 going on to task2"
```

So by using print statements like that i didn't need to have let's say a progressbar for example to indicate program progress. I added a QTextEdit widget in my gui and replaced all print statements in that function with:

`MyTextEdit.append('message')`

where `MyTextEdit` is a QTextEdit widget and `message` is the message i would like the function to print.

Example:

```
MyTextEdit.append('finished calculating task1 going on to task2')
task2 #lengthy second task
MyTextEdit.append('finished calculating task2 going on to task3')
task3 #lengthy third task
```

When i click the button and the function runs, all calculations inside that function have to finish and then all messages are appended to the QTextEdit widget.

I thought that each time a `MyTextEdit.append('message')` is executed it would run immediately and  the widget would display the message at that very instant and not at the end along all other messages.

What am i doing wrong?

I had the idea of doing this by reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356336/how-to-capture-output-of-pythons-interpreter-and-show-in-a-text-widget)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a call to [QCoreApplication.processEvents](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) after each `append`

You can get your instance of `QCoreApplication` with the static method `QCoreApplication.instance`

This will ask Qt to "refresh" your gui before finishing the tasks that are being executed, as the command processes all pending events.

Comment: Would care to add some more information as to why this worked, since i am a python and pyqt beginner?

Comment: I tried to add another paragraph explaining a bit more about it

Comment: Since the link you posted doesn't work anymore (404 error), here is a new one: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents