# PySide embeded Terminal Emulator

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I am making an application using PySide. I want to embed a Terminal Emulator (like the Linux Konsole, or xterm).  I want to have it in the application and not open up as a new window.

Does anyone know of any Python libraries that can do this? And how would I incorporate it, would I have to use a special QWidget to run it properly?

I also would like to be able to run linux commands.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the terminal with the python subprocess. I put down a little more info here [Terminal like app in PySide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436378/terminal-like-app-in-pyside) .

To embed it in your application just add the widget to the layout.