# Understanding a piece of python code

Tags: python, pyqt4, signals-slots

My question refers to the accepted answer of the question [How to capture output of Python's interpreter and show in a Text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356336/how-to-capture-output-of-pythons-interpreter-and-show-in-a-text-widget) which shows how to redirect standard output to a QTextEdit.

The author, Ferdinand Beyer, defines a class *EmittingStream* as such:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class EmittingStream(QtCore.QObject):

    textWritten = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def write(self, text):
        self.textWritten.emit(str(text))
```

He uses the class like this:

```
# Within your main window class...

def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
    # ...

    # Install the custom output stream
    sys.stdout = EmittingStream(textWritten=self.normalOutputWritten)

def __del__(self):
    # Restore sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

def normalOutputWritten(self, text):
    """Append text to the QTextEdit."""
    # Maybe QTextEdit.append() works as well, but this is how I do it:
    cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
    cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
    cursor.insertText(text)
    self.textEdit.setTextCursor(cursor)
    self.textEdit.ensureCursorVisible()
```

I don't understand the line that instantiates the *EmittingStream* class. It looks as if the keyword argument **textWritten=self.normalOutputWritten** connects the *textWritten*-signal to the *normalOutputWritten*-slot, but I do not understand why this works.

Comment: What exactly about this don't you understand? It's dead simple, you pass a reference to a function and the `EmittingStream` constructor (which is inherited from `QtCore.QObject`) connects it to the signal.

Comment: @l4mpi: That was exactly what I needed to know, it didn't occur to me that this behaviour is simply due to QObject's constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is [documented here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#connecting-signals-using-keyword-arguments):

> It is also possible to connect signals by passing a slot as a keyword
>   argument corresponding to the name of the signal when creating an
>   object, or using the pyqtConfigure() method of QObject. For example
>   the following three fragments are equivalent:

```
act = QtGui.QAction("Action", self)
act.triggered.connect(self.on_triggered)

act = QtGui.QAction("Action", self, triggered=self.on_triggered)

act = QtGui.QAction("Action", self)
act.pyqtConfigure(triggered=self.on_triggered)
```